# How to search text location in magento files in header section of the website?

Tags: php, magento, themes

I have tried to search header text in Magento File but not able to get it. 
Can anybody suggest where is the exact location of this text in Magento.

Given a try in Layout folder and in design folder via app folder but haven't got the exact location.
Find the screenshot below, to understand my problem.

Comment: text and screenshot both are missing.

Comment: http://screencast.com/t/VDW4o5wnr Pankaj please having look at this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

header text is not directly placed on the header file in magento, there are some static blocks that included in header, you can find the static block from magento backend  CMS->static blocks

Comment: Please check this screenshot for your reference , i have already given a try in back-end but not succeed.

Comment: check the code that place for this that will help you to know is that  code comes from backend or somewhere else. or check this file app/design/frontend/your-theme/template/page/html/header.phtml

Comment: Yes , got the answer. Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

Welcome text and logo image of header section can be found at the backend:

System > Configuration > under general, Design and then click on header section

Answer (score 0):

You can also edit any text directly from admin

System -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Developer -> Translate Inline -> Enabled for Frontend select "Yes" and save.

check on front side header text, you can see every editable text with book icon. please click on book icon and edit text which you want to change.